# Loading excel row(s) into an array, and writing then back to excel after a modification

Tags: arrays, row

I'm reading maximum 60 rows (one by one, based on certain criteria) from an excel sheet into an array.
Each line has 13 columns.

Initially I defined my working table as :

```
    Public WrkA As Variant
```

A Integer, called GenIdx is keeping the index of the next 'line' in my array

In a public sub, called LoadMyArr, I'm doing :

```
    WrkA = Array(1)
```

When I find a matching row in my sheet, I'm doing this :

```
    If WS1.Cells(ILine, c_Date) = CDate("03/07/2023") Then
            
            GenIdx = GenIdx + 1
            If GenIdx > 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve WrkA(GenIdx)
            Else
                ReDim WrkA(GenIdx)
            End If
```

Storing the row is done by :

```
     WrkA(GenIdx) = WS1.Range(.Cells(ILine, 1), .Cells(ILine, 13))
```

WrkA now has the weird structure :

```
     https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6Snb.png
```

When modifications are done, I need to push the data back to by sheet.

After opening the workbook for output, I loop through all the existing records until
I find the one that has the correct recordID (matching WrkA(1)(1,1).

At his point I'm stuck : how do I 'push' the content of WrkA(1) to the row in my sheet,
overwring all 13 colums with new values ?

Hints and tips are more then welcome :-)

Regards,

Martin

See details in the section above.